# Formula to get the accents in material design

Tags: color, material-design

We see here the palette of material design:

https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette

We see colors are at "500" and then they have gradations at 50, 100, and then A100, A200, etc.

What is the formula to get from say 500 to 50? Is it desaturate by 50% and lighten it by 10%? Or spinning the hue? I am using the color modification functions here - https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor#color-modification - which should match with w3 standards.

For instance Teal 500 is `#009688` and Teal 100 is `#B2DFDB`. What is the formula to get from 500 to 100 here?

The reason I ask is because in my app users can set a custom app theme, the color can be any color. But I want to make the gradations respect material design, as everything except the color is material in the app.

Thanks

Comment: It's not exactly clear how to do this. There's a clue in this question https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/43021/what-exactly-are-googles-500-color-swatches

Comment: Ultimately it's easiest to use a tool to do the work for you https://material.io/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0

Comment: Thanks @dennislees thats useful but not for my case. I explain why: The reason I ask is because in my app users can set a custom app theme, the color can be any color. But I want to make the gradations respect material design, as everything except the color is material in the app. Thanks also very much for the question link! I couldn't find that in my searches.

Comment: I think there isn't a linear formula to calculate the palette. Theoretical calculated colors MUST be adjusted to compensate our perception, contrast and an average output media accuracy. In short: they calculated each palette and then adjusted manually. For simple use cases you may interpolate in the HSL color space but you won't get the same _professional_ results.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Luckily enough we have non linear maths! And there are models about human perception of colour.

Comment: Here it's not about math. I doubt any color perception model (of a non existing average individual) can take into account how much aesthetically pleasant a color (and its pairing) is. You could find a formula (or probably a set of them) after the fact (manual adjustments after rough mathematical selection)

Answer (score 3):

This is extremely complex and convoluted. The most common way is to convert `hex` to `hsl` or `hsv`, get the value in that format and then convert back to `hex`. You can do it automatically using [this script](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256) which includes the specific FORMULAS (it's not just one)

If you want the specific formulas (again, FORMULAS) in more readable formats, you can try [HSV and HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

[image]

In short, to directly answer your question: first you convert your `hex` codes to `hsl` or `hsv`. Then you use the formula(s) you specifically need. For example, Teal500 is `0.4844, 1.0000, 0.5882` and Teal100 is `0.4852, 0.2018, 0.8745`. As you can see, very tricky, so I suggest you use the linked script or something similar and develop from there

Comment: Thanks Devin very very much. I can convert to hsv no problem. Its just once im there i dont know how to modify it get to the 100 shade. I tried two colors, Teal500 and Teal100, the difference between the HSV was: Teal500 - Teal100 = `{h:-0.26,s:0.798,v:-0.286}`. And from Red500 minus Red100 was: `{h:-349.89,s:0.583,v:-0.043}`. My reason for trying to figure out this calc is I allow my app to use custom non material color, but then i use material gradations. So was trying to figure out the calc to get from Any500 to Any100.